# Returning IDs with event numbers SELECT * query

Tags: java, mysql, database

This is my database reading code. But this shows only the items with even ID numbers (e.g: 2,4,6...). I tried to invoke an item with an odd number, but it returns an error as;

> inside rs false
>
> Error java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

How this could happen?

```
try {
       dbConnect dbConnect = new dbConnect();
       Connection currentCon = dbConnect.Connect();
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle";
       PreparedStatement ps = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
       while (rs.next()) {
           System.out.println("inside rs " + rs.next());
           ystem.out.println(rs.getInt("product_id"));
           rs.getInt("product_id");
       }
} catch (SQLException e) {
       System.out.println("Error " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ResultSet#next()` a second time inside the `while` loop.  Remove it:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("inside rs ");
   System.out.println(rs.getInt("product_id"));
}
```

Everytime you call `ResultSet#next()`, you advance the cursor of the result set by one.  This is why you seem to be moving through the result set by two records at a time.  So, you only need to do this in the loop control logic.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `rs.next()` moves the cursor to the next record and returns true if there was one, or false if there wasn't.

The problem is that in each loop, you are calling `rs.next()` twice.

If you remove the extra call and clean up the other code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int productId = rs.getInt("product_id");
    System.out.println(productId);
}
```

... this will solve both your problem of skipping every second entry, and reading past the end of the result set.